# ¿Cómo reducir contenido según el valor de la URL?

Tags: php

Me quiero evitar la fatiga de crear un archivo `HTML` por cada canal, y usar una mejor alternativa de manera dinámica usando `PHP`.

Tengo la siguiente lista de vídeos en formatos `.m3u8`

```
channel-dos.m3u8
channel-tres.m3u8
channel-cuatro.m3u8
channel-cinco.m3u8
```

Por medio del valor de la URL

```
example.com/content.php?channel=tres
```

quiero enviar esa información al reproductor, `javascript`:

```
{
   source: '<?php echo $channel; ?>',
}
```

Y así poder reproducir el archivo

```
channel-tres.m3u8
```

en caso de no tener un valor la `URL` =  example.com/content.php o un valor erróneo ocultar el reproductor  y mostrar un mensaje personalizado.

Me pueden explicar como aplicar el uso explicado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las alternativas de `else elseif` o `switch case break` no te ayudara/servirá evitar la agregación de una sola vez el código de `javascript` del reproductor.

La mejor manera de hacerlo es creando una lista, de valores permitidos, y mediante operadores `OR` o `||` ir agregando más de uno.

Ejemplo:

```
if(!isset($_GET['channel'])) {
    echo "No se muestra el reproductor"; //cualquier otro contenido.
} else {
    $channel = $_GET['channel'];

    if($channel == "uno" OR $channel == "dos" OR $channel == "tres") {
        echo "Permitidos"; // Contendio javascript
    } else {
        echo "error de url"; //Error de URL
    }
}
```

Mas información de los operadores.

Fuente:

- [Operadores lógicos](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php)
- [Logical Operators, || or OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998309/logical-operators-or-or)

Answer (score 1):

Lo más eficiente sería guardar la información en una base de datos, de manera que cuando se acceda a `example.com/content.php?channel=dos` se consulte en la base de datos a qué ruta corresponde `"dos"`. De esta manera cuando se quiera añadir un nuevo canal y por lo tanto un nuevo vídeo, no habrá que modificar el archivo `.php`.

Estructura:

```
+---------------------------+
| Channels                  |
+---------------------------+
| channel_id                |
| slug                      |
| route                     |
+---------------------------+
```

Datos:

```
+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
| channel_id  | slug        | route                    |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
|         1   | dos         | channel-dos.m3u8         |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
|         2   | lo-que-sea  | channel-siete.mp4        |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
```